# Learning conjunctions of Horn clauses

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I am studying the algorithm presented in this paper for ["Learning conjunctions of Horn clauses"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00992675).

The algorithm uses equivalence queries and membership queries to produce a formula that is logically equivalent to the unknown formula to be learned.

What I can not understand is how you can use this algorithm in practice since the formula to learn is unknown. If I do not know the formula I can not have an oracle telling me if a hypothesis is logically equivalent to the formula. If I know the formula I do not need an algorithm to learn it.

Is there a way to get an oracle without knowing the explicitly target formula or something I do not see?